# MYSQL ERROR - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update my `employees` table, but when I am trying, I get this error about `foreign key`.

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hrms`.`employees`, CONSTRAINT `Fk_Employee_Sections` FOREIGN KEY (`section`) REFERENCES `master_sections` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Here is my code

```
UPDATE employees e
JOIN testsection t
ON(e.employee_id = t.epfno)
SET e.section = t.id
```

Then I try this code, but it is still not working.

```
set foreign_key_checks=0 
UPDATE employees e
JOIN testsection t
ON(e.employee_id = t.epfno)
SET e.section = t.id 
set foreign_key_checks=1
```

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

Well you try to update the child-row `section` of your `employees` table. So far so good, but you try to write in a value from the table `testsection`. That won't work since the refernce points to the `id`-column of your `master_sections` table.
So the `section`-column will only accept values contained in the `id`-column of your `master_sections`-table. Otherwise it will fail.